# Parsing a JSON component whose structure is always changing in JAVA

Tags: java, json, parsing, jsonparser

I want to extract all the keys and value from a JSON component. The issue is the structure of this is unknown. I want to parse it in JAVA such that I can retrieve any element using the key/field name.

For example:

In this CustomError object is in this format.

```
"CustomError": "{\"errors\": [{ \"type\": \"INVALID_HTTP_VERB\", \"description\": \"Invalid HTTP verb for the requested resource\" }]}"
```

In this its in this format.

```
"CustomError": "{\"status\":{\"code\":104050,\"user_message\":\"Method Not Allowed\",\"developer_message\":\"Invalid http method or method not allowed\"}}"
```

My goal is to get all the keys and its value.

For 1st example :-

```
type : INVALID_HTTP_VERB

description : Invalid HTTP verb for the requested resource

For 2nd example :-

code : 104050

user_message : Method Not Allowed

developer_message : Invalid http method or method not allowed
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your requirement can be met by nearly all json libs out there

Comment: @davidgiga1993 I have tried by flattening Json, using JSONNode but the issue is I am not able to figure out when my key is in form of Array how to get the keys and value form that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Google gson library? If so you can use the JsonParser object like;

```
JsonElement j_element = new JsonParser().parse(YOUR_STRING);
```

Then you can step through the element in whatever form it's in, you can check types like `element.IsJsonObject()` or `element.IsJsonArray()` or whatever.

You can also turn the element into an object if is one, and do `object.has("value")` then if it is a `JsonObject` you can loop through the fields like;

```
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : YOUR_OBJECT.entrySet()) 
{
    //do further bits
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. Bur when I am trying to use this for my First nested JSON example. If i found that my entry.getValue().isJsonArray(). Then how to retrieve K-V from this JsonArray?

Comment: you can do `for (JsonElement ele : array.getAsJsonArray())` convert the element to to a json object then loop through the object like above.